# character encoding in websphere

Tags: websphere-7, url-encoding

Need help on character encoding for web sphere server. I am trying to insert **arabic** characters in DB. But its stored as `???????` 
When I changed the server to tomcat  it is inserting properly with arabic characters.
**What changes needs to be done to make it work with web sphere server.**

I tried by adding the value in server.xml

```
-Ddefault.client.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Still the issue continues.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to enforce an encoding by using the following JVM argument:

```
-Dclient.encoding.override=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thnx for your response, but still having the same issue.